# Image Upload - Returns file name not Image.

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload

I have worked on a script to allow users to upload a profile image. The image uploads fine, and I can update the image by uploading another -  But I am having a problem displaying the image when it has already uploaded, I get the file name but not the image. Is it because I am just trying to just Echo the table name 'profile' that the image is saved in. Or is it something els ?

- Also How can I modify the script to only allow a image of 500 x 500 to be uploaded ?

Image Upload Script:

```
    <div class="image-upload">

        <?php
        if (isset($_FILES['profile']) === true) {
            if (empty($_FILES['profile']['name']) === true) {
                echo 'Please choose a file!';
            } else {
                $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');

                $file_name = $_FILES['profile']['name'];
                $file_extension = end((explode('.', $file_name)));
                $file_temp = $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'];

                if (in_array($file_extension, $allowed) === true) {
                    change_profile_image($session_user_id, $file_temp, $file_extension);

                    exit();

                } else {
                    echo 'Incorrect file type. Allowed: ';
                    echo implode(', ', $allowed);
                }
            }
        }

        if (empty($user_data['profile']) === false) {
            echo '<img class="profileimg" src="', $user_data['profile'], '" alt="', $user_data['name'], '\'s Profile Image">';
        }

        ?>

        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" class="" name="profile"> 
            <input type="submit" class"">
        </form>

    </div>
```

Functions Script:

```
 <?php
   function change_profile_image($user_id, $file_temp, $file_extension) {
   $file_path = 'images/profile/' . substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . $file_extension;
   move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
   mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `profile` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($file_path) . "'   WHERE `user_id` = " . (int)$user_id);


   }

  //Select database, database_name needs to be changed 
  mysql_select_db("lr"); 

 //get decoded image data from database 
 $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE img='".$_GET['img']."'"); 

 //fetch data from database 
   $data=mysql_fetch_array($result); 
  $encoded=$data['data']; 

 //note: "$data['data']" is the row "data" in the table we made. 
 //The image ID would be "$data['img']" for example 


 //close connection 
 mysql_close($connection); 

 //decode and echo the image data 
  echo base64_decode($encoded);
```

Profile.php (Display Image) :

```
      <div class=".profileimage">
        <?php echo $user_data['profile']; ?>
      </div>
```

Any comments or feedback would be much appreciated, thanks (Y)

Comment: What's the value of `$user_data['profile']`? B/c it looks like it's the filename. You would want to echo it as the `src` of an `img` tag. E.g. `<?php echo "<img src=\"{$user_data['profile']}\" />"; ?>`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM images WHERE img='".$_GET['img']."'` this is really bad you should use mysqli or PDO

Comment: Also: isset() === true is unnecessary. [`isset`](http://ca3.php.net/isset) can only return `TRUE` or `FALSE`. You can change it to: `if(isset()){}` instead of `if(isset()===true){}`

Comment: @noahnu In the table, 'profile' is a Varchar with a value of 64; Yeah it seems I am just echoing the file filename that is saved in the table instead of the locating and showing the file

Comment: @meda Yeah I know, I should be using MYSQLI queries but I am just trying to finish off a project from my studies to brush up my PHP knowledge

Comment: if you saved the path why dont you echo it ? I dont think you need to encode it

Comment: I have inspected the page, and their is an image box (the question mark) to show an image is supposed to be shown, and the image file name (<img class="profileimg" src="images/profile/be657ce1e3.png" alt="Profile Image">) It is just a 250x250 image tag with the details but no image shown from the source